# LAST_VALUE() rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following

Tags: sql

What is the use of this statement?

Please elaborate with an example. I came across it while using the `LAST_VALUE` function.

Comment: -1 You should first try googling and searching for the answer. YOur question shows no research effort. Anyhow look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions063.htm

Comment: the question is not wrong! answer me if you can, else you have lot of other business

Comment: Please do not ask your question in the title. And don't be rude if you would like answers. This answer is available in [oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1018352), anyhow i will paste it here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Link Jan S. I am learning SQL using that link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1018352

when you ORDER a set of records in analytic functions you can specify a range of rows to consider,ignoring the others.
You can do this using the ROWS clause

UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
The range starts at the first row of the partition.

UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
The range ends at the last row of the partition.

CURRENT ROW
range begins at the current row or ends at the current row

n PRECEDING or n FOLLOWING
The range starts or ends n rows before or after the current row

Answer (score 1):

This is explained quite well in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS